# If there's no current through a battery, can it supply a voltage drop across a resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-measurement

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fflMr6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've solved for all of the currents in the circuit (I used an equivalent resistance for the middle two resistors) and the current through the 6V battery is 0 A. If there is no current through this battery, can it supply a voltage drop across the rightmost 600 ohm resistor? In other words, in this circuit, what is the voltage drop across the rightmost 600 ohm resistor?

Comment: As Claudio said you can remove the source because the 24V source with the voltage divider R1 with R2 || R3 provide the same voltage (6V) at the upper node. There is current through R3 (and R2) but it comes from the 24V source.

Answer (score 2):

If the current thru the power supply is zero, you can disconnect it. You can take out V2 and the circuit is unchanged.
The parallel of R2 and R3 is 200 Ohm. So the current thru V1 is 30mA (24V / (200Ω + 600Ω) ). The voltage drop thru R1 is 18V so the voltage on R2 and R3 is 6V, with or without V2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no. It's the 24V source that is supplying the voltage drop across R3 (and R2). Since there's no current through V2, you could disconnect it and nothing would change.